# Fifa 17 forcing me to create EA account

Tags: xbox-one, fifa-17

I've just started using Xbox one, trying to get Fifa 17 going from disc.

It seems like I have to create an "EA account" to be able to start the game. Is there any way around it? I thought offline playing would be possible, I guess I was wrong.

For a novice, it seems awfully hard to understand what an EA account is for and why it's mandatory. It is associated with tons of legal text.

Primarily, what I want to make sure is that I will not be charged for anything by EA in conjunction with playing Fifa 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to FIFA specifically, but these types of accounts are used by publishers to promote their own communities, distribution platforms (Origin, for EA), and subscription services (EA Access).  The legal text is just your standard End User License Agreement, the same kind you checked a box for when signing up for an account here.  On their own, the worst they'll do is send you emails advertising new games or sales.

With just an EA Account you shouldn't be charged for anything you don't explicitly sign up for, so if you don't want EA Access (which is a subscription charge), just don't sign up for that.  You can make sure this doesn't happen just by not giving it your card information at all, which will make it will prompt you for the info if you accidentally try to buy something, giving you the opportunity to back out.

Comment: You can unsubscribe from the newsletter, so you will not even receive emails from them.

Answer (score 2):

The EA-account is totally free, it's similar to a steam account.
You need this account to use the online features of all recent EA games (including FIFA). Furthermore it provides some online services e.g. cloud saving for your savegames etc.

You don't have to worry about this, it's a **standard practice** and it provides some helpful features. You will **never have to pay for creating and using such account**.